# C++ Normalizing Vectors; Error: cannot bind

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class Vectors
{
    public:
    Vectors(void);
    float X, Y;
    Vectors (float X, float Y);
    float magnitude();
    Vectors normalize();

};

Vectors::Vectors (float x_value, float y_value) {
    X = x_value;
    Y = y_value;
}

float Vectors::magnitude() {
    return sqrt(X * X + Y * Y);
}

Vectors Vectors::normalize() {
    Vectors my_vector;
    float length = this->magnitude();
    if(length !=0){
        my_vector.X = X/length;
        my_vector.Y = Y/length;
    }
    return my_vector;
}

int main() {
    Vectors my_vector(3.0,4.0);
    float mag_result = my_vector.magnitude();
    cout << "magnitude: " << mag_result;
    Vectors norm_result = my_vector.normalize();
    cout << "normalize: " << norm_result;
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to write something that will return the normalized/unit vector of a vector that is passed to it. I'm completely new to C++ so I can't make heads or tails of whether I'm even going about this right. Should my normalize function be returning anything at all? Or should it simply change the values of X and Y and then I access these from my_vector?

This is the error I'm getting currently:

```
In function 'int main()':
40:14: error: cannot bind 'std::basic_ostream<char>' lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/iostream:39:0,
                 from 1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/ostream:602:5: note: initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&&, const _Tp&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Tp = Vectors]'
     operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&& __os, const _Tp& __x)
```

Answer (score 1):

C++ only knows how to handle simple types when writing to cout.  Do you can't send the Vectors object directly to cout.  Instead, you need to send what you want to dump in simple terms.  I.e.

Vectors normal = 
cout << "normalize: " << norm_result.X << "," << norm_result.Y;

You'll probably want to place std::endl at the end of your dump of mag_result, too.

Answer (score 0):

norm_result is class, you'd better use class Vectors members X,Y instead.

Answer (score -2):

You'd better add a `friend` funciton for `ostream<<` for class vectors